# C++ Builder: "Disable compiler autodependency output"

Tags: c++builder

Do I need to keep "Disable compiler autodependency output" checkbox checked or not?

The documentation was written in a very confusing manner. Like they were by purpose trying to be confusing:

> Disables output of results of autodependency checking into the .obj
> file. The IDE uses the autodependency information (a list of the
> #include files in your project) to keep your object files up to date. If this option is enabled, the dependency checker does not rebuild
> source files whose Include files have changed. Default = False
> (Enabled)

When they say "if this option is enabled" they mean "the checkbox is unchecked".
And I guess I want it unchecked because I think I want to include changed files into my compilation. Right?

Answer (score 1):

As I read this, if you check this option, the compiler will save the output of results of autodependency checking into the .obj file. Help file says "If this option is enabled, the dependency checker does not rebuild source files whose Include files have changed."

The default project setting Project > Options > Building > C++ Compiler > Output for the Disable compiler autodependency checking is FALSE - meaning that autodependency info will be saved in the .obj file.

You can compare your unit's .obj file with the setting checked and not checked. The size of your unit's .obj file will about 1kb larger with the autodependency unchecked.

Note - this option is only available when you use the Classic Borland Compiler.

Comment: Thanks. And I want the feature enabled? I guess the answer is Yes. To have the changed files into my compilation. Right? Why would anyone not want this?

Comment: Leave the option unchecked and auto dependency will occur.